# Get data for every second in interval

Tags: postgresql

I want to write a query which will results value between timestamp at every second and if value for particular time stamp is not there then it should result zero.for example

- Start date time - `27/7/2015 10:00:00`
- End date time - `27/7/2015 10:05:00`

Then result should be

```
27/7/2015 10:00:00                10 [start date time]
27/7/2015 10:00:01                19
27/7/2015 10:00:02                23
27/7/2015 10:00:03                0 [Value not present in table for this timestamp]
27/7/2015 10:00:04                45
27/7/2015 10:00:05                0 [Value not present in table for this timestamp]
...
27/7/2015 10:05:00                42 [end date time ]
```

I am trying this query but not getting desired result

```
SELECT CAST(date_trunc('second', CAST(to_timestamp(t1.timestamp_col,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')as timestamp without time zone) + interval '1 second') as text) 
     , NULLIF(t1.y_temperature_col,'00')
FROM   historical_trend_data t1
WHERE  CAST(to_timestamp(t1.timestamp_col,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as timestamp without time zone) BETWEEN CAST(to_timestamp('28/7/2015 10:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')as timestamp without time zone) AND  CAST(to_timestamp('28/7/2015 18:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as timestamp without time zone);
```

This is the Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION timestampwise_sp2(IN startdatetime text, IN enddatetime text,
                                             OUT x_time_col text, OUT temperature text)
RETURNS SETOF record AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  return query
    with simul_data as(
      SELECT generate_series(startdatetime::timestamp,
                             enddatetime::timestamp, '1 Seconds') As x_time_col
    ) 
    Select simul_data.x_time_col::text, coalesce(t1.y_temperature_col, '0') AS temperature
    from historical_trend_data t1
    LEFT JOIN simul_data ON CAST(to_timestamp(t1.timestamp_col,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as timestamp without time zone) = simul_data.x_time_col;
END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

but it is not resulting the desired result

Comment: I have no time to write a complete answer, but you should look into `generate_series` to create a set of all relevant timestamps, `left join` to join your data to the series and add NULL values for missing rows, and `coalesce` to have NULL replaced by 0.

Comment: Apparently the "timestamp_col" is in text format, correct? If so, does it us the slash '/' separator or a dash '-'?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.sec AS obs_time, coalesce(t1.y_temperature_col, 0) AS temperature
FROM generate_series('28-07-2015 10:00:00'::timestamp,
                     '28-07-2015 18:00:00'::timestamp, '1 minute') AS s(sec)
LEFT JOIN t1 ON timestamp_col = s.sec;
```

The `generate_series()` function returns a set of records in a sequence, in this case second intervals from a starting point to an ending point. That is left-joined to your actual data and any `NULL` values for the temperature are converted to 0 with the `coalesce()` function.

In function form it would be like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION timestampwise_sp2(startdatetime timestamp, enddatetime timestamp) AS $$
  SELECT to_char(simul_data.x_time_col, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS x_time_col,
         coalesce(t1.y_temperature_col, '0') AS temperature
  FROM generate_series($1, $2, '1 second') AS simul_data(x_time_col)
  LEFT JOIN historical_trend_data t1
    ON to_timestamp(t1.timestamp_col,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') = simul_data.x_time_col;
$$ LANGUAGE sql STRICT;
```

Note that this is a `sql` language function, which is faster than `plpgsql`.

Comment: Using generate series in function is resulting into error.

Comment: Since you don't post the error I have to guess that it is the '/' slash separator in the `timestamp`; use a '-' dash instead. See updated answer (also note the closing quote mark on the interval).

Comment: i have edited my question with the function desired output is not resulting

Comment: generate_series needs timestamps, you are providings strings. You need to transform startdate just like you transform the column values with "as timestamp" instead of the :: operator. Also if you put the simul_data on the right, you need a right join instead of a left join.